# Do all number series have an $n^{\operatorname{th}}$ term function?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Do all sequences of numbers created by taking a number, performing an operation on it, then repeating this process $n$ times, have a corresponding formula for finding the $n^{\operatorname{th}}$ term without doing all the math in between? Like asking a question and skipping to the answer?

Comment: There's a thing called irreversibility and computational irreducibility. If you look at sequences as computations, then the latter term say that there is no way to shortcut the process in finding the $n$'th term without computing all steps inbetween (i.e repeating the process $n$ times as you say). This means not all sequences can be computed without running it for a while.

Comment: ... How is that possible? When you go through the process of calculation you effectively define a function over time... The only exception to this would be a truly random sequence, in which you can still express with a volume... So unless it loses the information through some sort of specific process, meaning that the sequence ends, like an infinite string of 0s... You should be able to get a function... Otherwise that implies randomness, it should just be complexity.

Comment: To rigorously answer this question you have to limit the tools which you allow to build your "shortcut formula". Otherwise I can just make up another function name for each sequence you are presenting me and stating "thats the function you are looking for". One possible restriction could be *computable functions*.

Comment: @M.Winter, I wasn't really implying you just "define" a function as the sequence, rather use the method you get the sequence to define a function. For when you work on an equation, continue a sequence, or get the answer from a computer, you're not just getting it from nowhere. Certain steps took place in such a way over an amount of time which got said answer, I was rather asking if you used that process to create a function that expresses that process over time, couldn't you just then "ask" what it will look like at a certain time and get the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's quite an abstract question, but if you are asking if having a starting point $x_1=a$, say and having some relationship between the elements of the sequence $(x_n)$ will always give a formula for $x_n$ then the answer is NO in the general case. Here is the following problem:

Let $x_1=a$. Define $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{2}$ if $n$ is even and $x_{n+1}=3x_n+1$ otherwise. Then if the answer to your question was YES then you could say whether the sequence could reach $1$ for any starting point $a$. The thing is, this problem is called the Collatz conjecture and it's open, i.e. no one can solve it fully. So I guess that means NO.

Another problem you might encounter is if you take repeated integrals, i.e. say you start with $x_1=1$ and take $x_{n+1}=\int_0^\infty y^{x_n-1}e^{-y}dy$ that is the Gamma function ($\Gamma(x_n)$). Since it doesn't have a closed form (different from the notation) then you want be able to have a decent expression.

However, if you have a linear relationship between finitely many of the entries in the sequence, then yes, you can use auxiliary equations to find a closed form provided you can solve a system of equations.

Hopefully that gave you an idea even though it's quite vague (I noticed you said just numbers in the beginning so I've assumed that means real\complex and not only positive integers).

Also, this might help: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/11vkk8/do_all_recursive_sequences_have_an_explicit_form/

Comment: Still new here so I don't really know how to write math properly into stackexchange, I'll try for this though. For example, an equation where the next number, a, is equal to a multiplier, A, times the previous number, P, plus the increment, B, modified by the modifier, C. The nth term version would be a(n)=lim(k->A)(((k^n)*(s*k+B-s)-B)/(k-1)) mod C, where s is the first number, for all positive integers. It should be at least, thats what I got. But I figured that this should be possible with any operation, so I have been trying with a=P^exponents, and so on...

Comment: So I was wondering if I was trying to do something impossible or perhaps just unexplored.